# React-bootstrap, not saved changes from Form.Control

Tags: react-bootstrap

I have a code:

```
<Form.Control
    type="text"
    name="username"
    value={Auth.getState.username}
    onChange= {(e) => {Auth.handleChange(e)}}
    placeholder='Введите Никнейм'/>
```

And have an error on "onChange= {(e) => {Auth.handleChange(e)}}": '19 stack frames were expanded.'

Please help, what's wrong?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was an error in function's name. Code 'onChange= {(e) => {Auth.handleChange(e)}}' work properly